# C# downloading of a webpage - Encoding

Tags: c#, html, encoding, character-encoding

I'm getting confusion about the Encoding issue. Traditionally, I'm using the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse to downloading webpage content.

Why confusion?

Since there are two parts of the content that holding the encoding:

1. HttpWebResponse includes the encoding of the document.
2. Webpage (HTML) it self includes  tags that define it's encoding.

Those two encoding can be conflict, one of them can be missing or wrong.

How should I determined which encoding is suitable for this webpage?

The solution needs to be universal - works with any HTML webpage.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to _process_ an HTML page consider the CsQuery library